# C# Webbrowser control not work like IE

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer

In my project i need to load website , the website contains JS scripts, it's fully compatible with IE and work fine in IE 11 on Windows .

in my project i use Windows Emulation registry technique to change IE version of WebBrowser control in C# and the Version() property of control and online website approve that my WebBrowser control is IE 11 .

Now some features of website in my own application not work and no error received from JavaScript codes , any idea ?

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but have you read through this blog post? It seems to have lots of good Information and might offer alternative approaches you could use: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility.aspx

Comment: WebBrowser control doesn't fully support all of the JavaScript and other features that a proper web browser does. If you want a good experience then use something like CefSharp or similar.

Comment: @Equalsk Do you have a source for that? I was under the impression it uses IE, and that while it defaults to IE7 compatibility mode you can force it in to other modes with a few different techniques. I'd love to read up on the other limitations of that control.

Comment: I don't have a source to hand right now, no. I'm sure it uses a stub of IE rather than being a full copy and therefore has limited capabilities with some things like JavaScript, Flash, ActiveX etc. I'm not going to go digging for sources, it's pretty common knowledge that the WebBrowser control is not great.